# uploading file data and textbox ,radio button values to database

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i like to upload a file in that form it contain some text boxes and one fileupload button,
how to do it in codeigniter,
when i did that in separately i can but with file upload i cant

```
function upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|txt|pdf|doc|docx';
    $config['max_size'] = '1024';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('js_home', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data(),'phone' =>$this->input->post('phone'),'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),'password' =>$this->input->post('password'));
        $this->jobseeker->storefile($data);
        $this->load->view('samples/upload_success', $data);// after uploaded the file
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any error to do it

Comment: do you want to store filename in the database

Comment: What is the problem ? You just have to update / insert in your database when the upload is ok.

Comment: Error : You did not select a file to upload.

Comment: So look to the name of your file input. By default, CodeIgniter search for the input called "userfile". If your file input doesn't have this name, so you have to put the name here : $this->upload->do_upload('fileinputname')

Comment: that if statement executes and return the error                            Error :  You did not select a file to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('js_home', $error);
    }
    else
    {
 $fInfo = $this->upload->data(); 

        $data = array('upload_data' => $fInfo['file_name'],'phone' =>$this->input->post('phone'),'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),'password' =>$this->input->post('password'));
        $this->jobseeker->storefile($data);
        $this->load->view('samples/upload_success', $data);// after uploaded the file
    }
```

in view `<input type='file' name='file'>`